# If $a,b,c,d$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, $a,b,c,d \gt 0$, and $ c^2 +d^2=(a^2 +b^2)^3$, prove that $ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

a,b,c,d $\in \mathbb{R}$  $a,b,c,d \gt 0$ and  $ c^2 +d^2=(a^2 +b^2)^3$ prove that  $$ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge 1$$

If I rewrite the inequation like $ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge \frac{c^2 +d^2}{(a^2 +b^2)^3}$ and manage to simplfy  it brings me nowhere. I try with 
Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but still can not solve it.
I would very much appreciate it if anyone could help me

Comment: are $$a,b,c,d$$ positive real numbers?

Comment: i think $a,b,c,d>0$ else inequality may not hold

Comment: yes , I am sorry ... positive and real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Titu's Lemma, we have

$$ \dfrac{a^3}{c} + \dfrac{b^3}{d} \ge \dfrac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{ac+bd}$$

So, we are left to prove that

$$ (a^2+b^2)^2 \geq (ac+bd)\tag{1} $$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) \geq (ac+bd)^2\tag{2}$$

Using the given proposition, $$c^2+d^2 =(a^2+b^2)^3$$ in $(2)$ and the fact that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R^+}$, we get $(1)$, which was required to be proved.

Comment: Titu's Lemma says $\frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y} \ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y}$ its not for the cubic power

Comment: @alana $\frac{a^3}{c}+\frac{b^3}{d} =\frac{\left(a^2\right)^2}{ac}+ \frac{\left(b^2\right)^2}{bd}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be Holder's inequality which gives:
$$\left(\frac{a^3}c+\frac{b^3}d \right)^2(c^2+d^2)\geqslant (a^2+b^2)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have ( for $x_i$, $y_i$, $p>0$):

$$\frac{x_1^{p+1}}{y_1^p} + \frac{x_2^{p+1}}{y_2^p}\ge \frac{(x_1 +x_2)^{p+1}}{(y_1+y_2)^p}$$

Just  equivalent to  [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), in this form it can be generalized to (positive) Hermitian operators. It says that the function $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{x^{p+1}}{y^p}$ is subadditive ( i.e., *convex*, since of degree $1$, like a norm...)

Back to our problem: can  we use the above inequality? Yes, with $p=\frac{1}{2}$

$$\frac{(a^2){\frac{3}{2}}}{(c^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}} + \cdots \ge \ldots$$