# $ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge 1$ prove inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that $ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$,  $a,b,c,d \gt 0$ and  $ c^2 +d^2=(a^2 +b^2)^3$. Prove that  $$ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge 1.$$

If I rewrite the inequation like $ \frac{a^3}{c} + \frac{b^3}{d} \ge \frac{c^2 +d^2}{(a^2 +b^2)^3}$ and manage to simplfy  it brings me nowhere. I try with 
Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but still can not solve it.
Plese help

Comment: Didn't you already ask that here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836753/prove-inequation

Comment: yes and is not solved

Comment: You want to say "inequality" because "inequation" is not a proper word.  Does seem like it should be a word now that you mention it.  But you'd just say "prove the inequality".

Comment: Thank you Gregory, I will edidt it

Comment: @alana It is solved and the answer there is correct.

Comment: I have been working on the solution for 2 hours but can not understand it , please help

Comment: @alana See my comment there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thank you ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

your inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{a^4}{ac}+\frac{b^4}{bd}\geq 1$$ and by CS we get
$$\frac {a^4}{ac}+\frac{b^4}{bd}\geq \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{ac+bd}$$ and we have $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\geq (ac+bd)^2$$
can you proceed?

Comment: The same solution is given in the linked question.