# How to prove $a^2/c + b^2/d \ge 1$ if $c^2+d^2 = (a^2+b^2)^2$?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R^+$.
I think we are supposed to use Cauchy-Schwarz here since it appeared in an exercise based on the same. At first, I thought it was a misprint of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836753/prove-inequation?noredirect=1), however, after trying out this in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tcqkrj7lxq), the red line does not go below the black one. Moreover, using Cauchy-Schwarz seems a bit weak as:
$$\left(\frac{a^2}c + \frac{b^2}d\right) (c+d) \ge (a+b)^2$$This leaves us to prove that $(a+b)^2/(c+d) \ge 1$ which is false for $a = 0.5,b = 0.1, d = 0.2$.
Can we prove this somehow (preferably using C-S, however I won't mind other methods)? Or can we find a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can show that
$$ \tag{$*$}
\left( \frac{a^2}{c} + \frac{b^2}{d}\right)^2 > \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{c^2+d^2} 
$$
holds for all positive real numbers $a, b, c, d$. The desired implication follows immediately.

*Proof* of $(*)$, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
 a^2 + b^2 = c \frac{a^2}{c} + d\frac{b^2}{d} 
\le \sqrt{c^2+d^2}\cdot \sqrt{\left( \frac{a^2}{c}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{b^2}{d}\right)^2} \\
< \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \cdot \left( \frac{a^2}{c} + \frac{b^2}{d}\right) \, ,
$$
now square and rearrange.

*Another proof* of $(*)$, by expressing the difference as a sum of non-negative terms:
$$
\left( \frac{a^2}{c} + \frac{b^2}{d}\right)^2 - \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{c^2+d^2}
= \frac{(a^2d^2-b^2c^2)^2}{c^2d^2(c^2+d^2)} + 2 \frac{a^2b^2}{cd} > 0 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Neither condition is affected if we replace $(a,b,c,d)$ by $(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda^2 c, \lambda^2 d)$ for $\lambda>0$. So we can choose $\lambda$ so that $a^2+b^2=1$, in which case we have $c^2+d^2=1$ as well.

Since $c>0$ and $d>0$, this can only hold if $c<1$ and $d<1$, which means that $\frac1c > 1$ and $\frac1d > 1$; therefore their weighted average $a^2 \cdot \frac1c + b^2 \cdot \frac1d$ is also greater than $1$.

Comment: So, does this mean that strict inequality holds?

Comment: It seems like it should, yes. However, we can make the sides arbitrarily close by approaching $(a,b,c,d) = (1,0,1,0)$ at an appropriate pace.